# How to get the Rhino edition of Less v.2.0.0 using bower as a package manager

Tags: less, bower

I'm using the Rhino edition of less.js, extracted to my devlopment environment using bower.

Under 1.7.5 everything worked fine, bower would get all the different editions, both Node and Rhino editions would be stored in my environment.

With the recent update to 2.0.0 it would seem that only the Node versions are included. Is there some way to get bower to extract the Rhino edition?

I can of-course download it manually, but then I would have to manually maintain that reference. Keeping track of new versions is one of my main reasons for using a package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Well from the comments of [How do I build the Rhino specific versions of less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810518/how-do-i-build-the-rhino-specific-versions-of-less):

@steve-eynon wrote:

> The GitHub Issue [Rhino Support in 2.x](The GitHub Issue Rhino Support
>   in 2.x suggests that there is no Rhino support for the 2.x versions...
>   :( ) suggests that there is no Rhino support for the 2.x versions...
>   :(

So currently you can't update the Rhino version of less.js with bower too.

according to http://github.com/Deraen/boot-less/issues/4 you should be able to use http://github.com/SomMeri/less4j without Rhino. And according to http://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2322#issuecomment-65631343 v2.1 should be the latest version working with Rhino.