# How do I build the Rhino specific versions of less?

Tags: gruntjs, less, rhino

I want to run the latest version of `less` from Java, for this (I believe) I need the Rhino specific versions of less. From the [less website](http://lesscss.org/#command-line-with-rhino):

> Each less.js release contains also rhino-compatible version.

But this appears to have been *not* the case [since v1.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959463/how-to-get-the-rhino-edition-of-less-v-2-0-0-using-bower-as-a-package-manager).

So I've installed NPM, installed Grunt, downloaded the less source from GitHub, ran `grunt -help` to find the `rhino` task but have fallen at the last hurdle:

```
C:\Temp\less.js-2.5.0> grunt rhino

Running "browserify:rhino" (browserify) task
Verifying property browserify.rhino exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "browserify.rhino" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Forcing doesn't help (produces an empty `lessc-rhino.js` file) - any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: try to run `grunt concat:rhino concat:rhinolessc`

Comment: That gives me the same result as using the `--force` option; the `lessc-rhino.js` file only contains a copyright comment and no javascript.

Comment: The GitHub Issue [Rhino Support in 2.x](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2316) suggests that there is no Rhino support for the 2.x versions... :(

Comment: i see, indeed the file is empty

Comment: according to https://github.com/Deraen/boot-less/issues/4 you should be able to use https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j without Rhino. And according to https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2322#issuecomment-65631343 v2.1 should be the lastest version working with Rhino

Comment: [Less4j](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j) looks to be a promising alternative - thanks!